# What side dish goes well with Peanut Chicken?

Tags: chicken

I am making dinner for my in-laws this weekend. I plan on making a Peanut chicken and pasta meal. The meal includes fettuccine, chicken strips, and pea pods in a peanut sauce. Do I need a side dish? If so, what would go along well with this meal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got some nice crunch and texture profiles in there already, but I tend towards always making a side dish to try to cover my bases in terms of getting plenty of options for people who might not like (or feel like eating) the main dish. My go to is a nice crusty bread with an unusual spread, but since you are going Asian-inspired here I would recommend something like rice paper spring rolls or to like an Indian-style samosa with a complimentary flavored potato filling.

Answer (score 1):

I think of Peanut Chicken as a Thai recipe, as such a light crispy salad as an appetizer and curry and rice side dish with mango and sticky rice as a desert would create a nice theme for the evening.

> Remember, behind every successful man is a surprised mother-in-law.